# Add user to Active Directory group results in "Access Denied"

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, active-directory-group

I am working on a C# Asp.net site that adds users to Active Directory and assigns them to security groups.

The whole script works great except for one issue. I can add users to groups, but I get an "Access Denied" exception when trying to add the user to a group that the Application Pool's Identity is a member of.

I think it's a windows permissions issue, but I'm not sure what permission is required. We had the same issue in the past when using an older VB script.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the identity of the Application Pool have privileges to add members to the group of which it is a member? That is, don't assume that an identity has the privilege to add members to a group merely because it is a member of that group.....or are you impersonating a specific identity at the time you perform the group addition?

Comment: I am using a specific identity (let's call him WebAdmin) for the entire app pool that has been given privileges to add members to groups. I'm not sure what extra privilege would be needed to add members to groups that "WebAdmin" is a member of himself.

Comment: you can also look at using directoryservices.  With this you can set the user which is making the ad calls and not have to mess with the application pool identity.

Comment: Unless I"m crazy (to which my wife would attest almost instantly), the ability to add members to a group is resolved to the *group* (specifically) - that is, there are several groups to which I can add members, and others I can't. Are you sure this identity has permissions to add users to the *specific* group in question?

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much! Write it as an answer so I can choose it. You had the best answer first.

Answer (score 1):

I had this kind of issue with a website designed for active directory management. The execution environment was not allowed to manage AD so far. So, through IIS, we changed the default account to local system, who has full permission (almost, he can't reboot the system for example) and cannot be logged (security first). This works for you are impersonating your website.

If not, You will need an advanced group and user management. AD permissions are very touchy.

**Edit:**
In your case, using a specific account is not a problem. Check the identity when your admin logs, and use impersonation with Local System. Your application environment will be alright, and only your admin will have an access.

Comment: Unfortunately not everyone using the site will be an admin. The IT workers most often using the site are not "Admins" just high level users. Do you know what specific privilege is allowing the admin to add to a group they are a member of? If I knew that I could add it to the app pool identity. Or is it simply not allowed unless you are an admin?

Comment: You need to set permission at the group, to allow a group to add user member to this group or organizational unit. And you can set these permission programmatically. But what I've done, it's a website where users log in. Depending their adminsitrative groups, they were allowed to access to certain functionality, and so on. So, they could access what their role could, but all the website was run by one account (Local System).

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I had to set the permission on the group itself.